# Inner product on the Hyperbolic half plane

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I think this is the dual question to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3099436/matrix-multiplication-on-riemannian-manifolds/3099477?noredirect=1#comment6394029_3099477).

From [Gudmundsoon](http://www.matematik.lu.se/matematiklu/personal/sigma/Riemann.pdf) notes, page 60:

We can model the hyperbolic space $\mathbb H^m$ as the super half plane space $\mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R^{m-1}$ with the metric

$$g_p(X, Y) = \frac{1}{x_1^2} \langle X, Y \rangle_{\mathbb R^m}, $$

where $x = (x_1, \dots, x_m) \in H^m$.

My question is: what is the relationship between the metric and the inner product? What is the "right" way of multiplying those vectors in a space that has this curvature? Clearly the "flat" one inherited from $\mathbb R ^m$ won't make much sense here.

Follow up question: more generally, what's the right way of constructing the inner product on $(\mathbb R^ m, g)$ for an arbitrary metric?

Comment: I'm no expert in Riemannian geometry, but I would assume that the inner product here is not of points from the manifold, but of tangent vectors in the tangent space at point $x$. Since the idea of Riemannian geometry is that the surface is locally Euclidean, using the regular inner product on those makes a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing some key concepts regarding tangent spaces and Riemannian metrics.

In general, a Riemannian metric on a manifold $M$ is a *family* of inner products, one for each point $p \in M$.

Given $p,q \in M$, the tangent spaces at $p$ and $q$ are disjoint vector spaces $T_p M$ and $T_q M$. The disjoint union of all these vector spaces is called the *tangent bundle* and is denoted
$$TM = \coprod_{p \in M} T_p M
$$

What a Riemannian metric does is to assign an inner product on each $T_p M$. There is not just *one* inner product.

In the example of $\mathbb H^n$, $T \mathbb H^n = \mathbb H^n \times \mathbb R^n$ and $T_p \mathbb H^n = \{p\} \times \mathbb R^n$. The vector space structure on $T_p \mathbb H^n$ is $(p,v) + (p,w) = (p,v+w)$, and $r (p,v) = (p,rv)$. Given $p = (x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb H^n$, and given $\vec v,\vec w \in \mathbb R^n$, what $g_p$ does is to assign the inner product 
$$\langle (p,\vec v) , (p,\vec w) \rangle = \frac{\langle \vec v, \vec w \rangle_{\mathbb R^n}}{x_1^2}
$$

Comment: So you are right I was skipping some details. I finally found what I was looking for: the Gyrovector space, a way of carrying over to the hyperbolic space some sort of euclidean space vector space structure.

Comment: Then my follow up question would be: is there a standard way of carrying over this construct to an arbitrary Riemann manifold?

Comment: The best thing to do with a followup question is to close out the current question and post a new question. No-one but me, or someone who reads these comments, will be aware of a followup question buried in the comments of my answer.